# Rails Installation of Spree Commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Hello im creating my first spree commerce and i did this

```
rails new spreecommerce
cd spreecommerce
```

i added this to Gemfile

```
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-0-stable'
rails g spree:install
rails s
```

now i can browse products and categories but /admin URL doesnt work.
so i tried

```
rake spree_auth:admin:create
```

but it says an error

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'spree_auth:admin:create'
```

Im too wonder where are controllers and views located ? not in spreecommerce/ directory where i installed application, how can i edit that app ?

if i run rake routes in spreecommerce/ directory i can see admin route

```
admin    admin/(.:format)     spree/admins/orders#index
```

but i dont have spree directory in that folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to run a `bundle install` after modifying your Gemfile.  That should make the spree_auth rake tasks available.

The controllers and views are all stored in the Gemfile.  You can execute `bundle show spree_auth_devise` to see where they are located on your system.  Note that you should not modify those files directly, as those changes won't be able to be deployed to a different environment.  You can refer to the [Spree Developer Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/) for more information on how to customize the controllers and views if you need.